# Creating an Azure CloudStorageAccount from a TokenCredential using a token obtained via Azure MSI

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I am attempting to create a `CloudStorageAccount` using an access token generated via MSI on Azure to be used in the Serilog Azure Blob Storage sink. I am getting a token and creating the account using the following

```
var tokenProvider = new AzureTokenProvider();
var token = await tokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://storage.azure.com");
var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential(token);
var storageCredential = new StorageCredential(tokenCredential);
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredential, "accountnamehere", "core.windows.net", true);
```

I then pass this account to the Serilog `LoggerConfiguration' as such

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    //other stuff
    .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(new JsonFormatter(), account, //other settings)
    .CreateLogger()
```

However, this never will write to the blob. My Azure account has both Contributor directly, and inherits Storage Blob Data Contributor from a group. The Azure VM I am working on also has Storage Blob Data Contributor to this storage account. However, in dev the credentials it is using are mine.

When I use the account key the blob is written to without issue, so something is either not correct with how I am generating the `CloudStorageAccount` or the permissions in Azure are not set up correctly, I am just not sure which.

Comment: Seems the sink needs an upgrade to the new Blob SDK :) Even if your approach did work, the token would expire after an hour and so wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: If this issue occurs in your dev env using your own credential which has no Storage Blob Data Contributor role of the storage account you are using, pls kindly add this role to your Azure account and try again. Based on my test, Inherited role seems not works here.

Comment: @juunas You can add a token refresh callback when creating the `TokenCredential`. That said, I have given up on this route because even with permissions set I can't get it to work.

Comment: So because I couldn't just let it go, I copied the above code into a fresh asp.net core project and tried it. Works just fine. As such, it has to be something configured strangely in my project. However, as this is the first code that is ever run I have no idea what the misconfiguration might possibly be.

Answer (score 0):

If this issue occurs in your dev env using your own credential which has no Storage Blob Data Contributor role of the storage account you are using, pls kindly add this role to your Azure account and try again. Based on my test, Inherited role seems not works here.

I have tested on my side, this is my code :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage;
using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Auth;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;
using System;

namespace AzureStorageTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var tokenCredential = new TokenCredential("<access token get from my account 
 whcih has the data contributor role of the stroage account that I am using now>");
            var storageCredential = new StorageCredentials(tokenCredential);

            var account = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredential, "<my storage account name>", "core.windows.net", true);


            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(account).CreateLogger();
            Log.Logger.Error("aaaaa");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Check my storage account , a log file is there :
[image]

Its content :

[image]

Comment: Even with that role set explicitly for my account it still does not work so it must be something with our setup that is preventing it from working. I have found a different solution through Key Vault which, to be honest, I am happier with anyway.

Comment: It's some whacked out permissions issue that I can't track down. Also, the empty project I used for clean testing is pulling the managed identity of my VM instead of my Azure account setup in Visual Studio which is why it is working. The permissions for my VM are somehow setup correctly, even though the permissions of my Azure account are exactly the same.

Comment: a bit late, but have you checked where your code is running? If IIS is hosting your code the MSI account isn't passed along from Visual Studio